battery level indication while charging
I am using this Module to indicate lithium ion battery level. I have seen many videos on this module, but it seems it is a voltage based module, so my question is while i am charging the battery, will this show the actual battery level? because while charging, the battery is raised to a higher voltage (say in CV region). which is NOT the actual battery voltage and since the module is in parallel it will show the level based on charger voltage, is that the case? Another question is, in constant current region, there will be a constant current from the charger to the battery, since the module is in parallel, so will the constant current damage this module?
Summary: Will this show proper battery level (based on current battery voltage) while charging?

There are several q&a on here about battery charging level - with checking out.

It should show battery capacity when charging or discharging, but neither mode will likely have the accuracy you're used to from most battery devices, which use coulomb counters.  This device is apparently based entirely on battery voltage.
In particular, it will show as charged too soon.  The charging cycle uses a constant current until a target voltage is reached, and then keeps the voltage constant until the current reaches nearly zero.  Of course, if that top bar is on at the target voltage (since this is the highest voltage it will encounter), it won't change as the battery finishes charging.
On discharge, it's difficult to say what to expect.  A typical fully-charged LiPo cell sits at 4.2V, but drops quickly to about 3.9V.  It then remains between 3.6 and 3.9 for most of its life cycle, dropping off fairly abruptly at about 20-30% charge.  I'd anticipate that it would show 100% or 75% through most of the discharge cycle, and those last three bars would start disappearing only when you got down to about 20%.  It's not so much a fuel gauge as a reserve tank.
All in all, for $3 and no design work, you have a working battery indicator, but you might have to spend some time learning exactly what's being indicated.

well I am using a charging module which is having a charge complete indicator. so you are saying before the target CV voltage is reached the indicator is approx, accurate based on the battery voltage right? now i am using an MCU which will continously connect and disconnect the indicator module so that it will always blink until it gets a charge complete signal (will use the chargers led) from the charging module. in that case "the charged too soon" wont be an issue right? since even all the bars are filled , it will still blink until it gets charge completion signal from charger

On charging, you'll probably indicate full when you're actually around 75%, but if you take that into account, it should be fairly linear.  Since your charger has an indicator signal, you can use that to determine full charge.  You can then use the indicator for immediate gratification, and the charger indicator for mission complete.  :-)
